# How to convert Datetime to Timestamp in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, unix-timestamp, derived-column

I'm new in SSIS. I'm importing an Excel Sheet to Transform and record in another Data Source. In the Transform process I need to convert some imported DateTime to their timestamp value

I always find Unix TimeStamp to DateTime in google search.

I'm using a derived column component.

I've tried this three expressions without any success:

```
DATEADD("ss",0,[DateToConvert])

DATEDIFF("ss",(DT_DBTIME)"1970-01-01",[DateToConvert])

(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)[DateToConvert]`
```

I Expect the output of `1571097600` for `15/10/2019`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Excel dates are *not* stored as Unix timestamps. They are stored in a format that's understood by SSIS and OLEDB already and *don't* need additional casting

Comment: What does the Excel file *actually* contain? Actual dates or integer offsets?

Comment: Excel dates aren't Unix timestamps. They are stored as [OA Dates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=netframework-4.8). They start from 1899-12-30, not `1070-01-01` but they *don't* need any kind of transformation as OLEDB already understands that type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, try the following expression, convert to `DT_DATE` or `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` instead of `DT_DBTIME`:

```
DATEDIFF("ss",(DT_DATE)"1970-01-01",[DateToConvert])
```

OR

```
DATEDIFF("ss",(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"1970-01-01",[DateToConvert])
```

Comment: Work As expected, you save my day